# Jenkins Project not running as Google Chrome is Timing out

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Google Chrome updated to version 73.0.3683.86 and Chrome driver was updated to 73.0.3683.68. when triggering a java project(TestNG) from Jenkins(as a service), the program runs indefinitely and does not get into the actual code and is timing out.

Tried downgrading the browser version to Chrome 71 and ran it through ChromeDriver version 2.46. This successfully runs the project. But the Automatic updates from Chrome gets pushed every night and makes it incompatible to the chromedriver version (Chrome version 73 and Chromedriver 2.46 - which will not work).

Tried updating both Chrome and Chromedriver to latest version and it wouldn't work.

Google Chrome is started, TASK MANAGER shows multiple instances of Chrome running (larger than usual number of instances when Chrome is Triggered through Jenkins). Killing random Google Chrome instance allows the program to run sometimes. But, our project requires scheduling projects every day in the morning automatically and hence, manually killing Chrome instance is not an option.

Started by user Automation Tester
Building in workspace D:\Code Backup\Code\General Revenue Content
[XXXXXXXXXX Content] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\a39974p\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins8618745924723016687.bat

D:\Code Backup\Code\XXXXXXXXXX >run.bat

D:\Code Backup\Code\XXXXXXXXXX >java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 6983
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Mar 28, 2019 11:50:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

[1553788844.734][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
[1553789144.734][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Expected: Chrome shouldn't be timed out and continue to execute the test script.

Actual : Chrome Time out after running for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, as far as I understood after test failure chromedriver doesn't close instantly but only after it reaches some timeout value(about 10 mins for me), but with older chromedriver version these closing chromedrivers were not occupying jenkins slots. 
 As a temporary fix I would advise you to downgrade to chrome v71 and disable auto update

Comment: Thanks Inl for your response, the issue is that the servers that we host the automation framework is under the company group policy which automatically updates Chrome every night.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the above comment, I would suggest the use of chrome version more than 72 and chromedriver version 2.46.

Or you can use combination mentioned on -

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for your response, the issue is that the servers that we host the automation framework is under the company group policy which automatically updates Chrome every night. I had been using the same version compatible Chrome and ChromeDriver. However, this is problem shows up every day due to the automatic updates to the server

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue while running Selenium tests in headless mode through Jenkins job. The console output was the following:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 36079
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Build timed out (after 5 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
Build was aborted
```

The issue was fixed by adding "--no-sandbox" to the ChromeOptions arguments.